# Erro: handle não declarado no escopo

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<time.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 90
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 26
#define WIN_WIDTH 70

using namespace std;

HANDLE console=getStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD cursorPosition;

int enemyY[3];
int enemyX[3];
int enemyFlag[3];
char car [4][4]={' ','Â±','Â±',' ',
                'Â±','Â±','Â±','Â±',
                ' ','Â±','Â±',' ',
                'Â±','Â±','Â±','Â±'};
                
int carPos=WIM+WIDTH/2;
int score=0;

void gotoxy(int x,int  y){
    if(size==0)
    size=20;
    
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO lpCursor;
    lpCursor.bVisible=visible;
    lpCursor.dwSize=size;
    setConsoleCursorInfo(console,&lpCursor)
}

void drawBorder(){
    for(int i=0,i<SCREEN_HEIGHT;I++){
        for(int j=0;j<17,j++){
            gotoxy(0+j,i);cout<<"+-";
            gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH-J,I);COUT<<"+-";
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<SCREEN_HEIGHT;i++){
        gotoxy(SCREEN_WIDTH,i);cout<<"+-";
    }
}               
void genEnemy(int ind){
    enemyX[ind]=17+rand()%(33);
    }
    void drawEnemy(int ind){
    if(enemyFlag[ind]==true){
    
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]);   cout<<"****";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]+1);  cout<<"**";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]+2); cout<<"****";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]+3); cout<<"**";
    }
}
    void eraseEnemy(int ind){
        if(enemyFlag[ind]==true){
            
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]);   cout<<"  ";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]+1);  cout<<"  ";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]+2); cout<<"   ";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind],enemyY[ind]+3); cout<<"   ";
    }   
}
void resetEnemy(int ind){
        eraseEnemy(ind);
        enemyY[ind]=1;
        genEnemy(ind);
}
void drawCar(){
    for(int i=0,i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            gotoxy(j+carPos,i+22);cout<<car[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void eraseCar(){
    for(int i=0;i<4,i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4,j++){
            gotoxi(j+carPos,i+22);cout<<" ";
        }
    }
}
int collision(){
    if(enemyY[0]+4>=23){
        if(enemyX[0]+4-carPos>=0&& enemyX[0]+4-carPos<9){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void gameover(){
    system("cls");
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"t\t--------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"t\t--------game over-------"<<endl;
    cout<<"t\t--------------------"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"t\tPress any key to go back to menu."<<endl;
    getch();
}
void updateScore(){
    gotoxi(WIN_WIDTH +7,5);cout<<"score:"<<score<<endl;
}
void instructions() {

    system("cls");
    cout<<"instructions";
    cout<<"\n--------------------------";
    cout<<"\n avoid cars by moving left or right.";
    cout<<"\n--Press 'a' to move left------------";
    cout<<"\n--Press 'd' to move right----------------";
    cout<<"\n--Press 'q'-to exit------------------";
    cout<<"\n--press any key to go back to menu.-------------------";
    cout<<"\n--------------------------";
    getch();

}
void play(){
    carPos=-1+WIN_WIDTH/2;
    score=0;
    enemyFlag[o]=1;
    enemyFlag[1]=0;
    enemyY[0]=enemyY[1]=1;
    
    system("cls");
    drawBorder();
    updateScore();
    genEnemy(0);
    genEnemy(1);
    
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +7 ,2);cout<<"car game";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +6,4);cout<<"------";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +6,6);cout<<"------";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +7 ,12);cout<<"control";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +7,13);cout<<"------";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +2 ,14);cout<<"A key -left";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH +2 ,15);cout<<"D key -right";
    
        gotoxy(18,5);cout<<"Press p key to start";
        getch();
        gotoxy(18,5);cout<<"           ";
        
        while(1){
            if(kbhit()){
                charch=getch();
                if(ch=='a'||ch=='A'){
                    if(arPos>18)
                    carPos-=4;
                }
                if(ch=='d'||ch=='D'){
                    if(carPos<50)
                    carPos+=4;
                }
                if (ch==27){
                    break;
                }
            }
            drawCar();
            drawEnemy(0);
            drawenemy(1);
            if(collision()==1){
                gameover();
                return;
            }
            sleep(50);
            eraseCar();
            eraseEnemy(0);
            eraseEnemy(1);
            
            if(enemyY[0]==10)
              if(ememyFlag[1]==0)
              enemyFlag[1]=1;
              
            if(enemyFlag[0]==1)
            enemyY[0] +=1;
            
            if(enemyFlag[1]==1)
            enemyY[1]+=1; 
            
            if(enemyY[0]>SCREEN_HEIGTH-4){
                resetEnemy(0);
                score++;
                updateScore();
                
            }
            if (enemyY[1]>SCREEN_HEIGTH-4){
                resetEnemy(1);
                score++;
                updateScore();
            }
        }


}
intmain(){
    
    setCursor(0,0);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    
    DO{
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(10,5 ); cout<<"------------------  ";
        gotoxy(10,6 ); cout<<"|   CAR GAME      | ";
        gotoxy(10,7); cout<<"  ------------------ ";
        gotoxy(10,9 ); cout<<"1.START GAME         ";
        gotoxy(10,10 ); cout<<"2.INSTRUCTIONS         ";
        gotoxy(10,11 ); cout<<" 3,QUIT        ";
        gotoxy(10,13 ); cout<<" SELECT OPTIONS ";
        
        if(op=='1')play();
        else if(op=='2')instructions();
        else if(op=='3')exit(0);
        

    
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}

    
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetStdHandle` é com letra maiúscula.

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem muita informação. Quando acontece o erro? Compilação? Qual é a mensagem exata? Você já tentou criar uma versão mínima do programa (cortando código até que o programa ficar o mais curto possível enquanto ainda mostrando o erro)?

Answer (score -4):

na Linguagem c / c++ , existem palavras reservadas , e não podem ser usadas pelo usuário em um programa , e "size " é uma delas , e muitos comandos são com letras minúsculas , e precisa usar a syntaxe correta também , por exemplo o "for" precisa de ponto e vírgula , e não vírgula simples , e no final tem fecha_chaves sobrando , e o código corrigido poderia ser assim  :

```
#define  _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#define  _h GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
#define  SCREEN_WIDTH 90
#define  SCREEN_HEIGHT 26
#define  WIN_WIDTH 70
#define  getch() _getch()
#define  kbhit() _kbhit()
using namespace std;

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD cursorPosition;

int  sizen = 0;  // size eh uma palavra reservada da linguagem C++
int  enemyY[3];
int  enemyX[3];
int  enemyFlag[3];
char car[4][8] =
{
    ' ' ,'Â±','Â±',' ' ,
     'Â±','Â±','Â±','Â±',
    ' ' ,'Â±','Â±',' ' ,
    'Â±','Â±','Â±','Â±'
};

int carPos = WIN_WIDTH / 2;
int score = 0;

void gotoxy(int coluna, int  linha)
{
    if (sizen == 0)
        sizen = 20;
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO lpCursor;
    //lpCursor.bVisible = visible;
    lpCursor.dwSize = sizen;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(console, &lpCursor); // faltou um ponto_e_virGuLa
    COORD c;
    c.X = coluna;
    c.Y = linha;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(_h, c);
}
void drawBorder()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++)  // virGulA o lugar de ponto_e_virgula e variavel i eh minuscula 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)   // virGulA no lugar de ponto_e_virgula
        {
            gotoxy(0 + j, i); cout << "+-";
            gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH - j, i); cout << "+-"; // j e i Sao minusculas
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        gotoxy(SCREEN_WIDTH, i); cout << "+-";
    }
}
void genEnemy(int ind)
{
    enemyX[ind] = rand() % 33 + 17;
}
void drawEnemy(int ind)
{
    if (enemyFlag[ind] == true)
    {
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind]); cout << "****";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind] + 1); cout << " **";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind] + 2); cout << "****";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind] + 3); cout << " **";
    }
    gotoxy(79, 25);
    //cout << "desenhou" << endl; getch();
}
void eraseEnemy(int ind)
{
    if (enemyFlag[ind] == true)
    {
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind]); cout << "    ";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind] + 1); cout << "    ";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind] + 2); cout << "    ";
        gotoxy(enemyX[ind], enemyY[ind] + 3); cout << "    ";
    }
    gotoxy(79, 25);
    //cout << "desmanchou" << endl; getch();
}
void resetEnemy(int ind)
{
   eraseEnemy(ind);
    enemyY[ind] = 1;
    genEnemy(ind);
}
void drawCar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // virGulA no lugar de ponto_e_virgula
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            gotoxy(j + carPos, i + 22); cout << car[i][j];
        }
    }
    gotoxy(79, 25);
}
void eraseCar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // virGulA no lugar de ponto_e_virgula
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)   // virGulA no lugar de ponto_e_virgula
        {
            gotoxy(j + carPos, i + 22); cout << " ";
        }
    }
}
int collision()
{
    if (enemyY[0] + 4 >= 23)
    {
        if (enemyX[0] + 4 - carPos >= 0 && enemyX[0] + 4 - carPos < 9)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void gameover()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "t\t--------------------" << endl;
    cout << "t\t--------game over-------" << endl;
    cout << "t\t--------------------" << endl << endl;
    cout << "t\tPress any key to go back to menu." << endl;
    getch();
}
void updateScore()
{
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 7, 5); cout << "score:" << score << endl;
}
void instructions()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n           instructions                    \n\
             \r-------------------------------------------\n\
             \r avoid cars by moving left or right.       \n\
             \r-- Press 'a' to move left -----------------\n\
             \r-- Press 'd' to move right ----------------\n\
             \r-- Press 'q'-to exit ----------------------\n\
             \r-- press any key to go back to menu . -----\n\
             \r-------------------------------------------";
    getch();
}
void play()
{
    carPos = -1 + WIN_WIDTH / 2;
    score = 0;
    enemyFlag[0] = 1; // VariaveL o no lugar do valor zero
    enemyFlag[1] = 0;
    enemyY[0] = enemyY[1] = 1;
    system("cls");
    drawBorder();
    updateScore();
    genEnemy(0);
    genEnemy(1);
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 7, 2); cout << "car game";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 6, 4); cout << "------";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 6, 6); cout << "------";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 7, 12); cout << "control";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 7, 13); cout << "------";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 2, 14); cout << "A key -left";
    gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH + 2, 15); cout << "D key -right";
    gotoxy(18, 5); cout << "Press p key to start";
    getch();
    gotoxy(18, 5); cout << "                    ";
    while (1)
    {
        if (kbhit())
        {
            char ch = getch();  // faltou hum espaço depois do char
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A')
            {
                if (carPos > 18) // faltou a letra c de carPos
                    carPos -= 4;
            }
            if (ch == 'd' || ch == 'D')
            {
                if (carPos < 50)
                    carPos += 4;
            }
            if (ch == 27)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        drawCar();
        drawEnemy(0);
        drawEnemy(1); // enemy com lera minuscula
        if (collision() == 1)
        {
            gameover();
            return;
        }
        Sleep(150); // funcao eh com inicial maiuscula
        eraseCar();
        eraseEnemy(0);
        eraseEnemy(1);
        if (enemyY[0] == 10)
            if (enemyFlag[1] == 0) // enemyFlag com "m" no lugar de "n"
                enemyFlag[1] = 1;
        if (enemyFlag[0] == 1)
            enemyY[0] += 1;
        if (enemyFlag[1] == 1)
            enemyY[1] += 1;
        if (enemyY[0] > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 4) // HEIGHT com T no lugar errado HEIGTH
        {
            resetEnemy(0);
            score++;
            updateScore();
        }
        if (enemyY[1] > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 4) // HEIGHT com T no lugar errado HEIGTH
        {
            resetEnemy(1);
            score++;
            updateScore();
        }
    }
}
int main()  // faltou um espaco depois do int 
{
    //SetCursor(0); // funcao com letra maiuscula
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    do // do é com letra minusculas
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(10, 5); cout << "------------------   ";
        gotoxy(10, 6); cout << "|   CAR GAME      |  ";
        gotoxy(10, 7); cout << " ------------------  ";
        gotoxy(10, 9); cout << "1 . START GAME       ";
        gotoxy(10, 10); cout << "2 . INSTRUCTIONS     ";
        gotoxy(10, 11); cout << "3 . QUIT             ";
        gotoxy(10, 13); cout << "    SELECT OPTIONS   ";
        int op = getch() - 48;
        if (op == 1)
            play();
        else
            if (op == 2)
                instructions();
            else
                if (op == 3)
                {
                    cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
    } while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `size` não é palavra reservada. Talvez vc tenha confundido com `sizeof`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword